# AngularJS assigning values to looped items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I've just finished a course on AngularJS, and I'm still a bit of a newbie. This is my first attempt at writing an app from scratch. I am attempting to build an app to keep track of game pieces from the recent monopoly game going on at many grocery stores. So far I have been able to loop each letter, with a loop inside that loop showing all game pieces assigned to that letter. Each letter will have it's own table containing all game pieces assigned to that letter. From here I want to be able to let the user + or - a value beside each game piece to keep track of how many of that piece they have. Is this possible? I have already put a loop inside of a loop, and I'm not quite sure how to loop the count of each piece beside the corresponding piece. I know this isn't the correct syntax to keep count of game pieces, but I've done plenty of googling and researching, and haven't found any article or tutorial to help me with what I'm trying to do.

Here is my js code from my controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('monopolyApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.pieces = [
      {
        letter:  'A',
        prize: '$100,000 Cash or Luxury Car',
        numbers: ['A500A','A501B','A502C','A503D','A504E'],
        count: [0,0,0,0,0]
      },
      {
        letter: 'B',
        prize: '$50,000 Home Makeover',
        numbers: ['B505A','B506B','B507C','B508D','B509E'],
        count: [0,0,0,0,0]
      }
    ];
  });
```

and here is the html from my view, but it's written in jade.

```
.container
  .col-xs-4(ng-repeat='piece in pieces')  
    table
      tr
        th Piece: {{ piece.letter }} |  Prize: {{ piece.prize }}
      tr(ng-repeat='number in piece.numbers')
        td {{ number }}
        td {{ count }}
```

So far I have only added the game pieces from A and B just incase it's not possible to do what I want to do, I didn't want to waste any unnecessary time. Any idea on how to include adjustable values beside each piece to let the user keep track of how many of each piece they have?

Thanks.

Comment: I am quite certain that what you want is absolutely plausible. However, I find it hard to understand what it is exactly that you want.

Comment: I'm sorry I've been googling and researching ways to do this all night, before asking here. I am still a very novice coder and I'm still trying to learn the appropriate way to ask a question where other people will understand what I am trying to do. I apologize for my 'newbie-ness'

I have looped the pieces for A and B into tables, with each corresponding game piece looped into those tables, and I'm trying to loop values into the same table next to the pieces to + or - values for how many of each game piece  the user has. Does this help at all? I apologize if I'm still not making sense to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really hard to understand what you what to accomplish.

> Any idea on how to include adjustable values beside each piece to let
>   the user keep track of how many of each piece they have

**Does it mean number of numbers in piece ?**

Then you can use `{{piece.numbers.length}}` in your template.

**Or you mean to output number count per each piece?**

Items from this value `count: [0,0,0,0,0]`? Then you can do it like this in the template:

```
tr(ng-repeat='number in piece.numbers')
        td {{ number }}
        td {{ piece.count[$index] }}
```

$index is an internally available value of the [current item in ngRepeat loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). So you can use this to access the corresponding value of the `piece.count` array.

Comment: The values in the count are supposed to correspond to each game piece in the numbers array. I was hoping to loop the values in the count array beside each item in the numbers array, but I understand this can be tricky as I am already doing a loop inside of another loop. I am about to go to bed now, but I will try this in the morning and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: "values in the count are supposed to correspond to each game piece in the numbers array" - that's exactly what I tried to do. Btw, loop inside of a loop is not a bad thing. if you have a 2 or more layers deep in your data structure it's ok.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I will try this in the morning and let you know how it goes. For now, I'm a bit too tired and I think I should get some rest before going any further. Thanks for the suggestion, and I'll be sure to try it first thing when I wake up tomorrow!

Comment: `{{ piece.count[$index] }}` worked in the way I intended. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can consider another way to model your data. Something like this:

```
$scope.pieces = [
    {
        letter:  'A',
        prize: '$100,000 Cash or Luxury Car',
        numbers: [{
            name: 'A500A',
            count: 0
        },{
            name: 'A501B',
            count: 0
        /* etc */
        }]
    }
];
```

Then the HTML would look like this:

```
.container
  .col-xs-4(ng-repeat='piece in pieces')  
    table
      tr
        th Piece: {{ piece.letter }} |  Prize: {{ piece.prize }}
      tr(ng-repeat='number in piece.numbers')
        td {{ number.name }}
        td {{ number.count }}
        td 
          a(ng-click='number.count += 1') Add count
          a(ng-click='number.count -= 1') Subtract count
```

Comment: I understand I could have probably done it this way, but it would require alot more code, I guess I was just looking for an easier way to do this with less code. I was always taught that the easiest/laziest way is the best way to do things, if possible....I suppose I could try this, I was just hoping to store the corresponding pieces to each letter in an array, since the game board has letters A-Z, plus even more pieces with special characters, with 5-8 game pieces corresponding to each letter. I will go this route of course if I can't find an easier way. Thanks!